# Application of the Dominated Convergence Theorem to differentiation inside the integral.

Tags: measure-theory

I'm currently looking at the p-Laplacian within the context of the calculus of variations. However, I'm struggling to apply the dominated convergence theorem to take a derivative inside an integral.

$\mathbf{Question}$

Assume $u$ and $v\neq 0$ are two functions in $W^{1,p}(U)$, $1<p<\infty$ and let $x\in U$ with $|\nabla u(x)|<\infty$ and $|\nabla v(x)|< \infty$ in Given the function
\begin{equation}
g:\tau\in \mathbb{R}\rightarrow g(\tau):=\frac{1}{p}|\nabla(u+\tau v)(x)|^p\in\mathbb{R}
\end{equation}
with $U\subset \mathbb{R}^n$
I can differentiate this with respect to $\tau$ to get 
\begin{equation}
g'(\tau)=|\nabla (u+\tau v)|^{p-2}(\nabla (u+\tau v)\cdot \nabla v)
\end{equation}
But what I would like to do is to apply the DCT to conclude that 
\begin{equation}
f:\tau\in \mathbb{R}\rightarrow \frac{1}{p}\int_U|\nabla(u+\tau v)(x)|^p\;dx\in\mathbb{R}
\end{equation}
is differentiable on $\mathbb{R}$ with
\begin{equation}
f'(\tau)= \frac{1}{p}\int_U|\nabla(u+\tau v)(x)|^{p-2}\big(\nabla u \cdot \nabla v+t|\nabla v|^2\big)\;dx\in\mathbb{R}
\end{equation}
So I'm looking to find an integrable function that dominates, say $|g'(\tau)|\leq h(\tau)$. However, I'm struggling to find such a function. If someone could offer a couple of hints I would be very greatful. I would really like to work through all the details as I'm sure this type of problem will come up again. I think my trouble comes from the fact that I'm dealing with vectors in the integrand which I haven't had much experience with. Sorry if this is a rather trivial question.

Comment: You say that $u,v\in\mathbb{R}^n$. However, from the rest of the question it seems that they are functions defined on $U$, since you are, among other things, taking their Laplacian. If that is so, you must know something about $u$ and $v$. As a bare minimum, they have second partial derivatives. What else do you know?

Comment: Sorry. I've edited the question and added a bit more detail. So I also know that $u,v\in W^{1,p}(U)$ and that the gradients are bounded. Apart from that I'm still stumped. I was wondering if youngs inequality on $g'(\tau)$ might help.